# How to check if my mouse is inside the Datagridview?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, mouseevent

I would like to check if my mouse is inside/outside the datagridview.  If I had my mouse outside, it should run my timer code to begin a countdown before it hides the datagridview (2 seconds in my example).. and if it is inside, the timer should reset my counter to 0 so as to not hide my datagridview..

below is the code of my timer.. w/ 100 interval

```
Private ctme As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If DataGridView1.Visible = False Then ctme = 0 : Exit Sub
        If Not DataGridView1.Bounds.Contains(PointToClient(Cursor.Position)) Then
            ctme = ctme + 1
            If ctme >= 20 Then
                ctme = 0
                DataGridView1.Visible = False
            End If
        Else
            ctme = 0
        End If
    End Sub
```

I have tried

```
Datagridview1.ClientRectangle.Contains(PointtoClient(Cursor.Position))
```

in place of

```
Datagridview1.Bounds.Contains(PointtoClient(Cursor.Position))
```

but still it doesnt work..

hope you could help me with this one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [MouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter.aspx) (Occurs when the mouse pointer enters the control) and [MouseLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave.aspx) (Occurs when the mouse pointer leaves the control) events:

using this the solution is much simpler:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseEnter
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseLeave
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Timer1.Interval = 2000
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    DataGridView1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate method using the MouseMove event of DataGridView to obtain the RowIndex and ColumnIndex of the cell the user is moving over.  If both indexes are not -1, the user is inside the data area.

```
private void DataGridViewComputers_MouseMove(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
            var dataGridView = (DataGridView)sender;
            var hitTestInfo = dataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            var rowIndex = hitTestInfo.RowIndex;
            var columnIndex = hitTestInfo.ColumnIndex;

            var insideDataGridView = (rowIndex != -1 && columnIndex != -1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to this on each event:

**MouseEnter**

```
Timer1.Stop()
```

**MouseLeave**

```
 Timer1.Start()
```

**Form1_Load**

```
Timer1.Interval = 2000
```

**Timer1.Tick**

```
DataGridView1.Visible = False
```